# Testing @MessageMapping WebSocket methods of Spring MVC controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-test

I am currently experimenting with the support for WebSockets added in Spring 4.0, as described in [this guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/). As demonstrated in the guide, methods annotated with `@MessageMapping` can be added to any Spring MVC controller, which may also contain `@RequestMapping` methods.

The spring-test module has support for writing integration tests for `@RequestMapping` methods (as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework)) in a very simple and fluid way:

```
@Test
public void getAccount() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/accounts/1").accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("Lee"));
}
```

Is there similar support for testing `@MessageMapping` methods using WebSockets? I have not found anything in any of the Spring modules, and none of the WebSocket guides contain any tests. If not, would I need to actually deploy the application and use a [`WebSocketConnectionManager`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/client/WebSocketConnectionManager.html) to connect a test client? Or is there some API I can build on from spring-test?

[This sample project](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-test/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/websocket/echo/StandardClientApp.java) contains such a small test client, but I would prefer to integrate this into the actual tests without requiring me to deploy the application and hardcode the deployed path in the tests.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing like Spring MVC Test for @MessageMapping methods yet. However, a similar approach to testing should be possible even without the fluent API. There is a ticket in JIRA (see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11266) to provide documentation so watch that ticket for more details in the very near future.