# What is the simplest way to cover websocket controller with unit tests in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-websocket

Is there something as simple as Spring [MockMvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html) for websocket testing?
I saw [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972223) questions/answers but all they are at least one year old and it seemed to me not so simple in terms of writing tests. 
Let's say I've got this controller:

```
public class ClieantQuery {
    private String name;
    private int count;

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public int getCount() { return count; }
}

@Controller
public class WSController {

    @MessageMapping("/ws-message")
    @SendTo("/message/data")
    public List<String> processClientQuery(ClientQuery clientQuery) {
        return IntStream.range(0, clientQuery.getCount())
                .boxed().map(i -> "Hello " + clientQuery.getName())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

How might look the class of tests?

Comment: This is not unit testing but integration testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the two methods mentioned here (https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/web) to test your controllers, using a `SubscribableChannel` as an alternative to `MockMvc` to send messages:

1. Tests loading Spring configuration: https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/web/context/ContextPortfolioControllerTests.java
2. Tests without loading Spring configuration: https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/web/standalone/StandalonePortfolioControllerTests.java